# download a csv zip file

Tags: csv, zip, r-markdown

I'm trying to download the following file.  The code works just find in RStudio when I run to the console.  But when I try to compile a markdown file (to either html or pdf), it gives an error.  Why can't markdown communicate with the csv zip file?

````
```
temp = tempfile()
download.file("http://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/Medicare-Provider-Charge-Data/Downloads/Inpatient_Data_2013_CSV.zip", temp)
temp2 = unz(temp, "Medicare_Provider_Charge_Inpatient_DRG100_FY2013.csv")
medData = read_csv(temp2)
```
````

Gives the following error (I had to remove URLs in error because I don't have enough reputation points):

> trying URL  Quitting from lines 41-49 (medicare.Rmd)  Error in
>   download.file("..",  :    cannot open URL '...' Calls:  ...
>   withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> download.file

Comment: The download function in the downloader package was an easy fix!   downloader::download("http://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/Medicare-Provider-Charge-Data/Downloads/Inpatient_Data_2013_CSV.zip", temp)